# Is there an IC like the ULN2003A but for high side switching?

Tags: switches

I'm looking for an IC to switch multiple ground-connected loads but having trouble finding a suitable chip. Is there anything kind of like a reverse ULN2003A but with a common collector and multiple emitters? Or just a bunch of MOSFETs with a common drain?

I need to switch 24V with 3.3V controller output.

Answer (score 3):

You could try searching for TD62783.  Not sure if they're still in production

Comment: This seems like a fine answer to me. It's not critiquing or requesting clarification.

Comment: That looks like exactly the sort of thing I need although that particular chip is no longer produced. I will see if there's a recommended replacement.

Comment: That IC is out of production and past EOL and a techno-dinosaur. It is on eBay at a premium cost, but nowdays high side power switching is being done by P-Channel MOSFETs due to their very low ON resistance and Vds drop.

Comment: **VFD driver** is actually a good search term. There are still some in production at reasonable prices (20-channel for $2).

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used M54564 for this purpose, but I do not know current availability.